# iOS8 UIAlertView blinks as it replaces white background with translucent one

Tags: ios8, uialertview, translucency

I'm seeing a strange behavior of one of my UIAlertViews, which I have not seen before. When shown on iOS8.0.2 it pops into existence with a white background, then it gets translucency effect applied to it. Because I'm showing it over a black background, there's a momentary flash as the background becomes translucent.

**Is there a way to disable translucent background for native iOS8 alert views?**

Comment: Apple deprecated `UIAlertView` in iOS 8.  Take a look at `UIAlertController` that might offer a solution.

Comment: Tried replacing it with the iOS8 equivalent, it still flickers as the background becomes transparent.

Comment: I checked the behavior of the iOS home screen "delete app" alert, and that one does not blink, My alert view blinks when displayed over a semi transparent UIView, maybe this is the reason why.

Comment: i am having the same issue and looking forward to solution

Comment: Same issue. Any solutions?